# Is specifying type and default value necessary in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular 2 app, is it necessary (or even best practice) to set the type if I set the default value?

ex.) Option 1

```
export class SomeClass{
    someVar: string = 'test';
}
```

Or this way:

ex.) Option 2

```
export class SomeClass{
    someVar = 'test';
}
```

In the above code, which is best practice for specifying **type** and **default value**? Option 1 or Option 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type is necessary for compilation. the actual value can change at runtime. the best thing if you specify a type of the variable and if you don't know a type at compilation time you might use `any` type. It's well described in [the language guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) for TypeScript language.

The variable can be initialized *inline* like in your code, or in constructor, or in the method/function. The *default* value should be determined at runtime if the variable is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript will guess the type using [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html). I personally prefer the type to be specified for variables and properties, but use inference for constants.